# What is the DRAG mouse stock cursor ID, wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

ive looked through the wxpython website however I do  not believe it has the stock cursor ID for drag.

Here is an image of the cursor:
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/truedbgrid8/ImagesExt/image19_31.gif

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor availability depends on OS. In Windows, None of the [available cursor](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Cursor-class.html) images correspond to the one you want. You can use the wxPython demo to check it for your OS (Demos -> Using images -> Cursor) although apparently there is no cursor with a promising name such as wx.DRAG_CURSOR.

However it is very easy to obtain a custom cursor using [wx.Cursor](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Cursor-class.html) or [wx.CursorfromImage](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#CursorFromImage) as in the example from [Driscoll blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/08/02/wxpython-messing-with-mouse-cursors/).

```
myCursor = wx.Cursor(img_path, cursor_type)
self.SetCursor(myCursor)
```